# read_html() reads a different URL from my input

Tags: r, url, rvest

I'm using rvest package in R. The `read_html()` function, sometimes it reads a different URL from my input URL. This happens when the input URL does not exist, so it automatically redirects to a similar one. Is there a way to read stop this auto-redirect?

```r
web <- read_html("http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/AAGE")
```

The above URL does not exist, so it actually reads information on the page http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Ag

I only want the information on the exact page if it exists.

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested only in the meaning results?

Comment: I am trying to get all the variations for a name. I have a name dataset that I need to go through, if any name in the dataset is not included in the website then I want to move to next one. Sometimes `read_html()` returns a error because the page does not exist, sometime it re-directs to a similar name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps think about if differently and do the POST request that searches for a given name. Then filter out results for meanings from return content using css attribute = value selectors. Then test the length of the results from filtering and if >0 generate the final url. There is then no re-direct. Even if you don't want the meaning url it effectively does the same thing. There will either be a length of zero when not found versus > 0 when found.

```
require(httr)
require(magrittr)
require(rvest)

name = 'Jemima'
base = 'http://www.thinkbabynames.com'
headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
body  <- list('s' = name,'g' = '1' ,'q' = '0')
res <- httr::POST(url = 'http://www.thinkbabynames.com/query.php', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = body)

results <- content(res) %>% html_nodes(paste('[href$="' , name,  '"]','[href*=meaning]',sep='')) %>% html_attr(., "href")

if(length(results)>0){
  results <- paste0(base, results)
}
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there should be a way to avoid the redirect and check whether the status code is 200 or 3xx with httr, but I'm not sure what it is. Regardless, you can check if the URL matches what it should:

```r
get_html <- function(url){
    req <- httr::GET(url)
    if (req$url == url) httr::content(req) else NULL
}

get_html('http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/AAGE')
#> NULL

get_html('http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Ag')
#> {xml_document}
#> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
#> [1] <head>\n<title>Ag - Name Meaning, What does Ag mean?</title>\n<meta  ...
#> [2] <body>\r\n<header id="nav"><nav><table width="1200" cellpadding="0"  ...
```

Comment: Ok, you can get it to error out with `r <- httr::GET('http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/AAGE', httr::config(redir_protocols = 0))`, but that still doesn't show you the 301

Answer (score 0):

Rvest can query pages as session objects that include the full server response, including the status code.

Use html_session (and jump_to or navigate_to for subsequent pages), instead of read_html.

You can view the status code of the session, and if it is successful (i.e., not a redirect), then you can use read_html to get the content from the session object.

```
x <- html_session("http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Ag")

  statusCode <- x$response$status_code
  
  if(statusCode == 200){
    # do this if response is successful
    web <- read_html(x)
  }
  if(statusCode %in% 300:308){
    # do this if response is a redirect
  }
```

Status codes can be quite useful in figuring out what to do with your data; see here for more detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes